# How to use SQL raw query in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

SQL table:

[image: SQL table]

```sql
SELECT id,
       account_name,
       parent_id
FROM
  (SELECT id,
          account_name,
          parent_id,
          CASE
              WHEN id = 1 THEN @idlist := CONCAT(id)
              WHEN FIND_IN_SET(parent_id, @idlist) THEN @idlist := CONCAT(@idlist, ',', id)
          END AS checkId
   FROM chart_of_account
   ORDER BY id ASC) AS T
WHERE checkId IS NOT NULL
```

When I run this query in MySQL it works fine and the result is fetched perfectly, but when I run it in Laravel like this:

```
$accountId = DB::select('SELECT id,account_name,parent_id FROM
                                    (SELECT id,account_name,parent_id,
                                        CASE WHEN id = '.$account_id.' THEN @idlist := CONCAT(id)
                                                 WHEN FIND_IN_SET(parent_id,@idlist) THEN @idlist := CONCAT(@idlist,', ',id)
                                            END as checkId
                                     FROM chart_of_account
                                     ORDER BY id ASC) as T
                                WHERE checkId IS NOT NULL');
```

it gives an error.

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Database\\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, string given,
```

Comment: If there be any chance of your query working in Laravel, you would probably have to execute a raw query.  And even then, I'm not sure that session variables would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = 'YOUR_QUERY_THE_BIG_ONE:)';
$result = DB::select($query,[]);
dd($result);
```

Optionally, you can use `?` sign in your query wherever you are using user inputs to prevent mySQL injection issue and then provide their value in second parameter array of `select` function. One example would be:

```
$inputUserEmail = $request->input('email');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?';
$result = DB::select($query,[$inputUserEmail]);
dd($result);
```

*I hope it gives you an idea*

Comment: its run perfectly tanx alot sir